How to discretize a parabolic problem with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions?
How do I correctly discretize a parabolic equation with homogeneous Dirichlet BC using finite differences? In particular, what is the explicit matrix form of the Laplacian in this case? (Basically, I want to implement the methods from Explicit exponential Runge–Kutta methods for semilinear parabolic problems.)
$$ \frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t} - \frac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial x^2} = \frac{1}{1+u(x,t)^2} + \phi(x,t), \quad u(0,t) = u(1,t)=0;\ x\in[0;1], \ t \in[0;1].$$
Assuming that the solution is $u(x,t)=x(1-x) \mathrm{e}^t$ (with an appropriate $\phi$), ${\partial u(x,t)}/{\partial t} = u(x,t)$ and ${\partial^2 u(x,t)}/{\partial x^2} = -2\mathrm{e}^t$.
Then, in Julia I have
module mwe

using Plots
using BandedMatrices

# space mesh
n_steps = 4
xs = LinRange(0.0, 1.0, n_steps + 1)
n_points = length(xs)
dx = xs[2] - xs[1]

# assumed solution
function u(x, t)
    return x * (1.0 - x) * exp(t)
end

# references
ref_du_dt(x, t) = u(x, t)
ref_d2u_dx2(x, t) = -2 * exp(t)

# full Laplacian
function laplacian1(n, dx)
    D_xx = BandedMatrix(
        0 => Fill(-2 / dx^2, n),
        1 => Fill(1 / dx^2, n - 1),
        -1 => Fill(1 / dx^2, n - 1)
    )
    return D_xx
end

# Laplacian only for interior points
function laplacian2(n, dx)
    D_xx = BandedMatrix(
        0 => Fill(-2 / dx^2, n),
        1 => Fill(1 / dx^2, n - 1),
        -1 => Fill(1 / dx^2, n - 1)
    )
    D_xx[[1, end], :] .= 0
    return D_xx
end

L1 = laplacian1(n_points, dx)
L2 = laplacian2(n_points, dx)

display(ref_d2u_dx2.(xs, 0) - L1 * u.(xs, 0))
display(ref_d2u_dx2.(xs, 0) - L2 * u.(xs, 0))

end # module

which returns
5-element Vector{Float64}:
 -5.0
  0.0
  0.0
  0.0
 -5.0
5-element Vector{Float64}:
 -2.0
  0.0
  0.0
  0.0
 -2.0

which does not match the true derivative at the endpoints of the space interval.
If the BCs were periodic, I would be able to reuse the values of $u$ by putting 1s in the  Laplacian matrix. But how do I compute the laplacian for the Dirichlet BC?

Instead of setting rows and columns equal to zero for the boundary nodes, simply remove those rows and columns from the matrix and operate only on the interior nodes.
